# Does SSH access trigger keyboard interrupts?

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard, proc

So, I've been studying the basics for my LPIC-1, and I have a question about `/proc/interrupts`

When consoled into a server, I can see key logging occurring (`cat /proc/interrupts | grep i8042` count for `1:` increases with each keystroke).

However, when I `ssh` into the box, no matter how many times I `echo` absurd amounts of text, the `i8042` count never increases.

Are keystroked logged against `/proc/interrupts` when accessing servers via `ssh`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `i8042` is the keyboard controller. The key counter will be only incremented by a real keyboard.

When you are entering via ssh, you are using a pseudo-tty and obviously not using the local (physical) keyboard. There are no IRQs there for the keys.

I will leave a link detailing this.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/linux-interrupts/

Comment: I was aware of that, thought maybe it would be logged as a different device or similar. Thank you!

Comment: ssh packets would be counted as interrupts on a NIC device, along with other network traffic

Comment: yep, that is why I wrote "for the keys" ;)